# how to display data from both two tables in database in a View in mvc4 razor

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Can anybody guide me how to display data from two tables in database in view page of MVC4 using razor?i googled it but i didnt find answer for this

LeadDetail.cs

```
 public partial class LeadDetail
 {
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
    public string LeadName { get; set; }

    public virtual logintable logintable { get; set; }
 }
```

EmployeDetail.cs

```
 public partial class EmployeDetail
 {
    public int EmployeID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }


    public virtual logintable logintable { get; set; }
  }
```

Parentview.cs in viewmodels folder

```
 public class Parentview
 {
    public List<LeadDetail> LeadDetails { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeDetail> EmployeDetails { get; set; }

    public ParentsInformationViewModel(List<LeadDetail> _LeadDetails, List<EmployeDetail> _EmployeDetails) //Should i pass all the required parameters that i want to display in view ????
    {
        LeadDetails = _LeadDetails;
        EmployeDetails = _EmployeDetails;

    }
```

Homecontroller.cs

```
 public ActionResult view()
    {
        List<LeadDetail> LeadObj = new List<LeadDetail> ();
        List<EmployeDetail> EmployeObj = new List<EmployeDetail> ();
        // get list of parents here

        Parentview   ParentInfoVMObj = new Parentview();
        ParentInfoVMObj.LeadDetails = LeadObj;
        ParentInfoVMObj.EmployeDetails = EmployeObj;


        return View(ParentInfoVMObj);
    }
```

Comment: Create a view model containing 2 collection properties, one for each table.

Comment: You need to create view model for that , the combination of two table models

Comment: @Stephen Muecke see my updated code and please guide me

Answer (score 0):

see below sample

**First Table**

```
public class Table1
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

**Second Table**

```
public class Table2
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModelForTwoTables
    {
        public List<Table1> table1Data { get; set; }

        public List<Table2> table2Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: i am very new to asp.net so please pardon me to ask such a small thing,i have done till to this but st uck in controller and view page , can u show how to do this for particular condition in controller and view page...here its not just displaying data from tables ,here i have to display data for same userid from both tables when user click on particular userid.

Answer (score 0):

see below example

```
public ActionResult TeamStat()
{
 var players = db.Players().ToList();
 var seasons = db.Seasons().ToList();
var view = new TeamStat()
{
Players = players,
Seasons = seasons
};
return View(view);
}
```

in view

```
@foreach (var player in Model.Players) { .... 
@foreach (var player in Model.Seasons) { ....
```